Make an adaptive swiper on vue
I have a swiper component connected via script in index.html <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>
here is the swiper itself:
<swiper-container class="swiper" :slides-per-view="5" :space-between="20">
    <swiper-slide v-for="(film, index) in films" :key="index" class="swiper-slide">
      <div class="swiper-slide__container" @click="selectFilm(film)">
             <img class="swiper__img" :src="film.imgUrl" :alt="film.imgAlt">
         <a class="swiper-link">{{ film.link }}</a>
      </div>
   </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

and I can't figure out how to make it adaptive for smaller screens. Namely the value :slides-per-view="5" to do something less. At least 3 for example. Or there is no way to do this at all and you will have to hide it somehow or just change it at a certain width of the window.
If anyone has encountered and knows the solution to the problem, I will be very grateful
I tried me through the code, but whatever you write there will still give an error, and through media queries I think it will not be possible to change this property

swiper.js is mobile responsive compoent. which exact problem do you have? plase add additional inofmation, screenshots, playground links

my swiper has :slides-per-view="5", and I would like the value of :slides-per-view="" to become smaller when the screen size decreases. For example, not 5, but 3, so that the cards in the swipe look normal.

gotcha. added the answer below

You can use breakpoints prop to do exactly what you want.
See the official demo and Breakpoints API in Docs for more
<template> 
    <swiper-container
    :slidesPerView="1"
    :spaceBetween="10"
    :breakpoints="{
      '640': {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 20,
      },
      '768': {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 40,
      },
      '1024': {
        slidesPerView: 5,
        spaceBetween: 50,
      },
    }"
    class="mySwiper"
  >
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>
</template>


hah. good point. my example does exact the same but with additional package. nice

@BorisMaslennikov Thanks! Swiper exposes a lot of APIs that handles a lot of cases if not all of them

you can use vue-responsiveness npm package (docs here) for example:
main.js:
import { VueResponsiveness } from 'vue-responsiveness'
app.use(VueResponsiveness)

App.vue:
<template>
   <swiper-container class="swiper" v-bind="swiperOptions">
      <swiper-slide v-for="(film, index) in films" :key="index" class="swiper-slide">
         <div class="swiper-slide__container" @click="selectFilm(film)">
             <img class="swiper__img" :src="film.imgUrl" :alt="film.imgAlt">
         <a class="swiper-link">{{ film.link }}</a>
      </div>
      </swiper-slide>
   </swiper-container>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useMatches } from 'vue-responsiveness'

const matches = useMatches()

const swiperOptions = computed(() => {
  switch(matches.current)
  {
    case 'xxl': return { slidesPerView: 6, spaceBetween: 25 };
    case 'xl': return { slidesPerView: 5, spaceBetween: 20 };
    case 'lg': return { slidesPerView: 4, spaceBetween: 15 };
    case 'md': return { slidesPerView: 3, spaceBetween: 10 };
    case 'sm': return { slidesPerView: 2, spaceBetween: 5 };
    case 'xs': return { slidesPerView: 1, spaceBetween: 2 };
    default: return { slidesPerView: 0, spaceBetween: 0 }
  }
})
</script>

if you don't use ES and write you app in index.html you can use this code instead of using npm package:
const breakpoint = ref('')

onMounted(() => {
  updateBreakpoint()
  window.addEventListener('resize', updateBreakpoint);
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', updateBreakpoint);
});

const updateBreakpoint = () => {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 576px)').matches) {
      breakpoint.value = 'xs';
  } else if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
      breakpoint.value = 'sm';
  } else if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 992px)').matches) {
      breakpoint.value = 'md';
  } else if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)').matches) {
      breakpoint.value = 'lg';
  } else if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1400px)').matches) {
      breakpoint.value = 'xl';
  } else {
      breakpoint.value = 'xxl';
  }
};


and then use breakpoint variable in swiperOptions computed property
please let me know if you have any questions left.
ps: don't forget to upvote my post and mark it as answer if you found it useful

thanks for the answer!. I'll finish what I'm doing now and try.
